# how to include custom field values inside the post widget in elementor

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I have some post which have custom field values. So when showing the posts using the Elemetor Pro **posts widget** I want to add the values of some custom field in the same post.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is choose a widget that has a field that supports Dynamic Content and choose that option on the field.

Complete and official explanation here: https://docs.elementor.com/article/381-elementor-integration-with-acf

Comment: Thanks for the Answer but I want to solve the solution by changing the source code of the post widget

Comment: Then you have to either create a new skin for the posts widget or use https://wordpress.org/plugins/ele-custom-skin/

Comment: Do you have any Idea about changing the source code of the widget

Comment: In your plugin folder /wp-content/plugins/elementor-pro/modules/posts/skins there are the skins that come by default. See how they are made and you can make a new one